# compare md5sum of a file online versus and that file locally downloaded

Tags: r, windows, cmd, md5sum

Should I expect these md5sums to be the same?

```
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml'
shl = paste0('curl -s ', url, '|md5sum')
shell(shl, intern = T)
#"1dbeef7406e5054197382916ff72e29b *-"

fl = 'temp.xml'
download.file(url = url, destfile = fl, mode = 'wb')
tools::md5sum(fl)
#"96bdf6d80c0bb6e27620079e2f6f7237"
```

If not, is comparing files like this generally possible?

Or is there another method to check that files are not corrupted during download if the source does not provide checksum?

UPDATE:

```
url = 'https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/Data/bin/latlon.bin'
shl = paste0('curl -sL ', url, '|md5sum')
shell(shl, intern = T)
#"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e *-"

fl = 'temp'
download.file(url = url, destfile = fl, mode = 'wb')
tools::md5sum(fl)
#"1a1eeb7a09418f047588148395096b91"
```

It seems to return different md5 values if the file is `.bin`

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing two different files - `curl` doesn't automatically follow redirects

```
curl -i http://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml                                                                                                                                    [13:00:20]
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml
X-Request-Guid: 99819f8c-f481-4295-b527-f586b9e27d22
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self'
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Content-Length: 157
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 17:00:23 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-lga21947-LGA
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1560531623.276827,VS0,VE3
Vary: Fastly-SSL
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Set-Cookie: prov=48b775d0-60fb-3f52-5066-61fe6fab27ca; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Use -L to follow the redirect:

```
curl -sL http://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml | md5                                                                                                                             [13:00:23]
96bdf6d80c0bb6e27620079e2f6f7237
```

Comment: Your answer fixed that problem, but I should have picked a better example. The file I'm working with is a binary one. Even with `-sL` it returns different md5 values

Comment: Well then, I'd bet that there's some other default behavior of `curl` that doesn't match that of `download.file`. Investigate the headers you're getting back from `curl`, or maybe try `wget` instead?

Comment: ruling out wget vs curl (they're returning the same)